# $\Delta U$, $C_p$, $C_v$ for an ideal gas process

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there any way to generally demonstrate $C_p=C_v + R$ using thermodynamic cycles?

Comment: I deleted my answer below, because I posted a little prematurely and didn't look at the problem carefully enough. Are you treating the oxygen as an ideal gas? If so, surely $\Delta U_2 = 0$, since the energy of an ideal gas is only temperature dependent.

Comment: For step 3 you need to explicitly state that it is a constant pressure process. The fact that the initial and final pressures are the same does not necessarily mean it is a constant pressure process

Comment: For a mathematical proof that the internal energy of an ideal gas is a function only of temperature, irrespective of the process, see my Answer in the following thread:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428947/why-is-the-change-in-internal-energy-in-an-isothermal-system-for-an-ideal-gas-ze.  Furthermore, regarding your previous comment, $Q=C_vdT$ only for a constant volume process.  But, for ANY process, $\Delta U=C_v\Delta T$

Comment: @santimirandarp. I will show you why initial and final pressures being the same doesn't mean it has to be a constant pressure process when I present a revised answer. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @santimirandarp. I think I would rather post if for all. One reason is that I think you have made some good questions that should be addressed for all to see.  If you would rather I not, let me know and I will not pursue it further.

Comment: Yes.  It is an experimental fact that real gases approach ideal gas behavior in the limit of low pressures, and, in this limit, their behavior is observed experimentally to be described by $\Delta U=C_v\Delta T$.  This is in every thermodynamics textbook out there.  For a differential change between two thermodynamic equilibrium states, dQ=TdS and dW=-PdV.  When you learn about the second law of thermodynamics, you will cover this.  The differential form is important because it focuses on how the physical properties of the material vary, irrespective of the process the material experiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the central points in these discussions concerns the relationship between internal energy and temperature for the case of an ideal gas. In particular, the fact that the change in internal energy for an ideal gas, for ANY process, is given by

$$\Delta U = C_v\Delta T$$

The question has been raised, “is $\Delta U = C_v\Delta T$ for ANY process an experimental fact?” I think this is a very good question. After all, why should it be true if the process is not a constant volume process? What if it is a constant pressure process? Or an adiabatic process? As turns out $\Delta U = C_v\Delta T$ for these processes as well due to the relationship between the specific heats and gas constant for an ideal gas..

**For a constant pressure process:**

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$
$$\Delta U=C_p\Delta T – P\Delta V$$
For one mole of an ideal gas
$$P\Delta V=R\Delta T$$
Therefore 
$$ \Delta U=C_p\Delta T – R\Delta T$$
$$R=C_p-C_v$$
$$ \Delta U=C_p\Delta T – (C_p-C_v)\Delta T$$
$$\Delta U=C_v\Delta T$$

**For an adiabatic process (Q=0):**
$$\Delta U=-W$$
$$\Delta U=- \frac {R\Delta T}{1-k}$$
For an ideal gas
$$k=\frac{C_p}{C_v}$$ and
$$R=C_p-C_v$$
Therefore
$$\Delta U=- \frac{(C_p-C_v)\Delta T}{1-C_p/C_v}$$
$$\Delta U= C_V\Delta T$$

So if one accepts the fact that for any process $\Delta U=C_v\Delta T$, then $\Delta U_2 =0$, and replacing (3) into (1) gives $C_p-C_v=R$. (See an alternative proof below that does not depend on processes.)

But the question was raised, what about the work in step 2?  The expression given for the work is based on the assumption that step 2 is an isothermal (constant temperature) process (more about processes below). We don’t know from the diagram whether $V_0$ is greater than or less than $V_1$. Let’s assume $V_1 > V_0$. In that case, for an isothermal expansion, the work done by the gas (energy out) exactly equals the heat transferred to the gas from the surroundings (energy in) which is has a temperature greater than $T_1$. All this occurs in such a way that the temperature of the gas, $T_1$, remains constant and therefore there is no change in internal energy.

**DISCUSSION OF PROCESSES:**

The diagram designates pressure, volume and temperature for three equilibrium states. The processes involved in going between these states are not explicitly stated but presumed to be constant volume (step 1), constant temperature (step 2), and constant pressure (step 3), because the initial and final volume, temperature and pressures are the same as the initial values.  However it should be noted that simply specifying the initial and final states does not define the paths between the states. This is not important with regard to the changes in properties, such as $U$, which are independent of the path, but it is important when determining work or heat transfer as these are path dependent. For example, in step 3, the work done assumes a path involving a constant pressure process.  But we could just as well chosen a path consisting of a constant temperature process followed by a constant volume process. See the diagram below. For this case the work done (area under the path) will be less than that for a path involving only constant pressure.

Hope this helps.

**ALTERNATE PROOF**

Another way of proving $C_p-C_v=R$ is by using the basic definitions of the specific heats and enthalpy, combined with the ideal gas law.

Specific heat definitions, ideal gas (they are actually partial derivatives holding P and V constant, respectively):
$$C_p = \frac {dH}{dT}$$
$$C_v = \frac {dU}{dT}$$
Definition of enthalpy (H)
$$H = U + PV$$
For one mole of an ideal gas, ideal gas law
$$PV=RT$$
Therefore
$$H = U+RT$$

Taking the derivative of the last equation with respect to temperature:
$$\frac {dH}{dT} =\frac {dU}{dT}+R$$
Substituting the specific heat definitions into the last equation, we get
$$C_p – C_v = R$$

[image]

Comment: @ArnabChowdhury The definitions of $C_v$ and $C_p$ in terms of $U$ and $H$ are fundamental so they come first. Then $R=C_{p}-C_{v}$  comes from combining them with the ideal gas law.