# Why is internal energy determined by macroscopic variables?

Tags: thermodynamics

We usually say that internal energy $U$ is a state function and hence specifying the state of the system determines the internal energy. But most often we write $U = U(P, V, T)$ leading me to believe that the *macroscopic state (macrostate)* of the system determines the internal energy. Now I understand why a *microstate* of the system would determine internal energy, it's obvious from what internal energy means physically. But I don't see why a set of microstates corresponding to the values of a set of macroscopic variables $(P, V, T..)$ should all correspond to exactly one energy macrostate. Can someone explain the reason to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't see why a set of microstates corresponding to the values
>   of a set of macroscopic variables $(P, V, T..)$ should all correspond
>   to exactly one energy macrostate. Can someone explain the reason to
>   me?

Let me preface my answer by saying I am not conversant in the subject of statistical mechanics, but rather continuum thermodynamics. From a continuum thermodynamics perspective, we can deduce how, as you say "a set of macrostate variables should all correspond to exactly one energy macrostate" by a step by step process.

1. The first law of thermodynamics ties internal energy, $U$, a state function, to the two possible means of energy transfer, heat and work.
2. Though heat and work are not state functions, in the state variables ($P$, $V$, $T$) for the process involved are used to calculate heat and work.
3. Equations of state describe the unique relationship that exists between the state variables that determine internal energy, under equilibrium conditions.
4. Finally, it follows from 1-3 it can generally be shown that a unique relationship among state variables ($P$, $V$, $T$,...) determines establishes a unique value for another variable, in this case internal energy $U$.

Let's apply 1-4 to the simple case of an ideal gas.

1. We start with the first law of a closed system (no mass transfer).

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

2. For a reversible process, the boundary work $W$ done between two states is determined by two state variables, pressure and volume.

$$dW=PdV$$

$$W=\int_1^2 PdV$$

To make the calculation we need to know how pressure varies as a function of temperature. In short, the work done will depend on the process (path) between states 1 and 2.

In the case of heat transfer, $Q$, it is due solely to temperature difference, a difference between two values of one property, and the specific heat capacity of substance. For a gas, the specific heat depends on the process.

For a constant pressure process, we have $dQ=mC_{p}dT$. For a constant volume process, $dQ=mC_{v}dT$

3. For an ideal gas, the equation of state that provides the unique relationship between the macrostate variables ($P$,$V$, $T$) od

$$PV=nRT$$

Moreover, for an ideal gas, the molar specific heats are related to the gas constant $R$ by

$$c_{p}-c_{v}=R$$

4. Using the last three equations, we can deduce, for any process, for an ideal gas the relationship between internal energy and the macrostate variables boils down to two, temperature and specific heat.

$$\Delta U=c_{v}\Delta T$$

Which tells us that, for an ideal gas, the internal energy depends only on temperature. For details on how this relationship was deduced, see my answer to the question posed in the following link.

[$\Delta U$, $C_p$, $C_v$ for an ideal gas process](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428778/delta-u-c-p-c-v-for-an-ideal-gas-process/429472#429472)

Hope this helps.

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to say that the equation of state is expressed in terms of the macroscopic variables (usually), and the energy transporting quantities - work and heat - are also written in terms of these macroscopic variables. Any 'good' theory should be able to do this. And these two further imply that $\Delta U$ can be expressed solely by these macroscopic quantities. In other words, we _conjecture_ (based on the expectation that the theory is 'good') that since the system is described by macroscopic quantities pretty well, the internal energy should be as well.

Comment: @adch99 Well, what you call  “conjecture” has enabled us to use these relationships to determine the amount of work that can be produced by heat engines and how efficiently they can do so for a few hundreds of years. Seems like more than “conjecture” to me.  So I really don’t know what it is you are looking for. I’m going to leave it at that and move on.

Comment: I think I didn't put it forth correctly. What I meant was that while we tend to assume these for a general thermodynamic system, it in fact depends on our working models/theories of each system separately. It has to be shown separately for each system and each model of that system. That's what I meant by _conjecture_.

Comment: @adch99 Sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the statistical mechanics is pretty much to *describe the state of a system of many particle in terms of macroscopic variables*. The introductory chapters of statistical physics textbooks usually clarify this (with variable success), and then define *microcanonical distribution* as the average over *all the microstates corresponding to the same energy*.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, there is no reason for it to be true. We have to look towards other structure. The argument comes from the First law, which gives you the condition that $U$ is a state function, and any change due to work done depends only on initial and final conditions. For an adiabatic process, this is

$$\Delta W = E(x_f) - E(x_i)$$

We want to argue further that the coordinates $x_i$ and $x_f$ may be expressed in terms of macroscopic variables only, and we are not required to fully define $x_i$ in terms of a particular microstate. Suppose that we do a *quasi-static* transformation, such that the process is done sufficiently slowly that the system is always in equilibrium. Since internal energy is a state function, it does not matter which path we take, so we always choose a quasi-static path.

At equilibrium, we can describe a particular state (which is a really collection of microstates) by macroscopic variables. Thus, the coordinates $x_i$ and $x_f$ may be defined fully by variables such as $(P,V)$, or $(B,M)$ and so on.

Comment: What about the change in U due to heat transfer Q? Why are you omitting that from your first equation?

Comment: Thats a mistake, that equation is for adiabatic processes. Edited, but the point is just to reiterate that internal energy is a state function, as op said.

Comment: Yes it is a state function, but I don't think the OP is debating that. If I understand the OP correctly, what is not understood why a set of macroscopic properties (variables) should all correspond to one state function.

Comment: Yes, and the explanation for that is that since a state function is path independent, we can always choose a path which is slow in time so that at every point the internal energy is at equilibrium. Equilibrium conditions are best described by macroscopic variables. The ability to do so is basically the entire point of statistical mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Now let's suppose there is some form of energy which is not expressed by the macrostate $U = U(P, V, T)$. i.e., for the same macrostate $(P, V, T)$ there are multiple possibilities of internal energy $U_1, U_2, U_3,..$. That means the conservation of energy no longer holds! Every time we find that the conservation of energy doesn't hold, it suggests that there are some hidden form of energy (perhaps electromagnetic energy or interfacial energy or something more mysterious). We go on to add another variable accounting for the new energy and revise the macrostate to $(P, V, T, x)$, and now $U = U(P, V, T,x)$.

The new problem is, how do we know if $x$ is necessarily a macroscopic state variable? why not a microstate? Could $x$ be the horizontal velocity of one particle? In order for this particle to be able to change $U$, it must have a considerable amount of energy. If $U=10^{23} (1/2 m v^2)$, then $1/2 m x^2$ must be much much larger than $1/2 m v^2$. And in this egalitarian world of thermodynamics, if one particle has too much energy, everyone wants a share of it, and everyone eventually gets a share, through numerous collisions. Eventually every particle would in average have the same amount of energy, that's called the **equipartition principle**.