# Determining properties of air

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, home-experiment

Is there any way to theoretically obtain values of specific volume, internal energy, enthalpy and entropy of air, assuming it's an ideal gas?

---

Can it be done using ideal gas laws?

Comment: Do you mean changes ($\Delta$) in these properties?

Comment: Well, really, I want an explanation. How does one calculate these. To answer your question, sir––yes.

Comment: @bobd Sir, do you think there is a way?

Comment: Sure. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can determine such properties by combining the ideal gas law with the first and/or second laws.

For example, by combining the ideal gas law and the first law of thermodynamics, you can show that, for any process, the change in specific internal energy is a function of temperature only according to

$$\Delta u=c_{V}\Delta T$$

For the derivation see here: [$\Delta U$, $C_p$, $C_v$ for an ideal gas process](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428778/delta-u-c-p-c-v-for-an-ideal-gas-process/429472#429472)

In a similar way you can show, for air as an ideal gas and a constant pressure process,

$$\Delta h=c_{P}\Delta T$$

Combining the ideal gas equation, first and second laws we can show:

$$\Delta s=R ln\frac{v_2}{v_1}$$

as follows:

From the second law, for a reversible isothermal process we have

$$q=T\Delta s$$

From the first law we have

$$\Delta u=q-w$$

Since, for an ideal gas isothermal process, $\Delta T=0$, then $\Delta u=0$, and $q=w$, therefore

$$T\Delta s=w=\int Pdv$$

From ideal gas law, one mole of gas

$$Pv=RT$$

$$P=\frac {RT}{v}$$

$$T\Delta s=\int \frac {RT}{v}dv$$

and finally

$$\Delta s=R ln\frac{v_2}{v_1}$$

Hope this helps.